# Create multiple parts of complex model in the main view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a little new to ASP.Net MVC, I have a complex model.

```
public class BuildingPermit
{
    public int ApplicationID { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Applicant { get; set; }
    public virtual Area ApplicantArea { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
    /...
}
```

Using scaffolding, I created the controller and all the views. However, I want to register all the details in the same page, meaning in the `BuildingPermit`'s `Create` view, creating the details for `Applicant` of type `Person`, the `ApplicationArea` of type `Area` and so on. Is there any way I can accomplish this?

If it's not possible, I think it's possible to add a link to create the object. When the user clicks on it, the page goes to that view, creates it, get its information back and shows it in the `BuildingPermit`'s view.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by creating an editor template for Person, Area, Owner etc in:

```
~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Person.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Area.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Owner.cshtml
```

The editor template will want to be strongly typed and should give the editor layout for the type:

```
@model Models.Person
<h2>Person</h2> 
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
</p>
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
</p>
// And so on
```

Once you've done this calling `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Applicant)` will pick up your template and display within your Edit view.

If you are wanting to display all of this information together then you will probably want to also create display templates for these types. These work just like the editor templates except you keep your templates in a DisplayTemplates folder.

```
~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Person.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Area.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Owner.cshtml
```

Comment: Amazing. Can I just copy the "Edit" or "Create" templates for Person, etc. To the "EditorTemplates" folder? If so, which one should I copy?

Comment: One more question. I copied and edited the "Create" view of Person and added the `@Html.EditorFor...` to the view and it worked. However, I'm not sure how the create request works. I mean, when I click the submit button of the parent view (`BuildingPermit` above) will it automatically post and save the required information for all the tables? Or should I handle this manually?

Comment: Your scaffolding files will be set up to post to your controller. You will want to remove the `@Html.BeginForm()` and any Create or Edit headings. Your template should only contain what is needed to display the template, i.e. `@Html.LabelFor()`, `@Html.TextBoxFor()`, `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` and so on.

Comment: You would expect the creation of the whole BuildingPermit object to be handled by one action/post. Your parent view should already be hooked up to post to a Create action in your controller. The model passed back to this method will contain all of your complex properties for BuildingPermit so you can handle creation of the data here.

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly. However, there is a slight problem. In my model, there is a property like this: `public virtual ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }`. Although I have the template for `Owner` set up, it doesn't show anything. What should I change? I want to show a list to the user and the user can add as much as he likes.

Answer (score 0):

That's no problem, just make sure you initialise your complex object somehow to avoid null reference exceptions:

```
public BuildingPermit()
{
    this.Applicant = new Person();
    this.ApplicantArea = new Area();
    ...
}
```

Then in your controller action method create an instance of the model and pass it to your view:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    BuildingPermit model = new BuildingPermit();

    View(model);
}
```

For the view:

```
@model MyNamespace.BuildingPermit

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Applicant.FirstName)<br />
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Applicant.FirstName)<br />

...

<input type="submit" value="Create new building permit" />
```

Then look into examples online on how to handle a `HttpPost` in your MVC controller.

If you want to create specific UI partials for each object type, then you can looking into `EditorFor` and `DisplayFor` templates.  From what you mention in your original post, this might be what you're looking for also.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Between this method and the one suggested by @Macs which one is the more "official" way?

Comment: @Macs is a really good answer, it's a good description of using `EditorFor` templates which seems to be what you're looking for.  Both are valid approaches, but the `EditorFor` solution gives you more flexibility if you're going to be editing/displaying the Person, Area and Owner objects in other Views.