# EditorTemplate for creating an ICollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Using the method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896978/create-multiple-parts-of-complex-model-in-the-main-view) I managed to create a view for most of my types. However there are 2 collections which I'm having problems with.

```
public class BuildingPermit
{
    public int ApplicationID { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Applicant { get; set; }
    public virtual Area ApplicantArea { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
    /...
}
```

As I mentioned in the linked question, I created the controller and all the views for my custom types using scaffolding and I want to register all the details in the same page (view), meaning in the `BuildingPermit`'s Create view, creating the details for `Owners` with the type `ICollection<Owner>`. The other types are behaving as they should but not the `ICollection` ones.

I want to make the user be able to somehow register a few `Owner`s in the `BuildingPermit`'s create view. If it's not possible, at least create 1, 2, or 3.

Thanks in advance.